# How to disable Drawer in nested component in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, router, react-navigation, drawer

Consider the render of the `Main` component:

```js
render() {
 const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;
 return (
  <View>
    {isAuthenticated ? <Dashboard /> : <Login />}
  </View>
);
```

I want to lock the drawer in the `Login` component. Now i know that i could achieve this if `Login` wasn't a child of `Main` this way (in my `Router` component):

```js
   Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
        }),
    },
```

But since `Login` is a child of `Main` and `Main` has the drawer, `Login` will automatically have the drawer too. I've tried "overriding" it by calling this in `Login`:

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
  };
```

But no success. Here's my `Router`:

```js
const Stack = {
    Main: { screen: Main },
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
        }),
    },
    Outbox: { screen: Outbox },
    Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
    JobList: { screen: JobList },
    CreateJob: { screen: CreateJob },
    Reporting: { screen: Reporting },
    JobDescription: { screen: JobDescription },
};

const DrawerRoutes = {
    DrawerStack: {
        name: 'DrawerStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(
            Stack,
            {
                initialRouteName: C.MAIN,
                headerMode: 'none',
                navigationOptions: {
                    gesturesEnabled: false,
                },
            }),
    },
};

export const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
    Drawer: {
        name: 'Drawer',
        screen: DrawerNavigator(DrawerRoutes, {
            contentComponent: DrawerPanel,
        }),
    },
    ...Stack,
}, { headerMode: 'none' });
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: This is only appears in react-navigation v2+. If you use v1.5.x it works fine. Do not know why they removed this feature.